# How do I use my work Outlook 2016 email with Outlook 365? Or use something other than outlook for my email client?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, office365, email-client

My job email is set up through Outlook 2016 on our own domain name. I've set up my own personal domain email address to route to Google Inbox no problem. But I'm unused to Outlook and don't exactly know how to do something similar with the Outlook 365 web app. Is that even possible?

I would much prefer to use Outlook 365 because I like the interface better. Though I'm also thinking about just routing it into Inbox also. I just want something that's easier to keep tidy.

Also maybe I'm just totally off the mark here on what I want to do because I'm honestly not sure I understand the difference between Outlook 2016 and 365.

Comment: You can only do this if your an Administrator within the Office 365 domain.  Guessing that isn’t the case.

Comment: @ramhound Ah. So I guess that means my admin has to pay for office 365 subscription or something right? Any alternatives? I could take a look at thunderbird but I imagine that's just as ancient in it's design as Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between the service that provides you with an email address and a mailbox, and the application that you can run on your desktop to read your emails.

With the Outlook **application** you can connect to any email account. It could be your company email on your on premises Exchange servers, or an Office 365 email account hosted in the cloud, or an email account with Gmail, etc. Once set up in the desktop application, you can switch between the different mail boxes in that one application.

If you access any web client, however, i.e. use email in the web browser, these are linked to only one account. So, you can access your Gmail in the browser and log in with your Gmail account. Your company may offer a web version of your Exchange email account. Office 365 offers browser based email handling. Outlook.com has a web interface. And so on. But each online service can only handle one account and you cannot open another email account from a web app email session.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the web version of our email service which runs a web version of Outlook that is similar enough to Outlook 365 (also loaded it inside of Rambox so I could keep it separate from my normal internet browsers and next to my chat and slack windows. )